# SpringBoot/Swagger, Show only specific Controllers on Swagger?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

- Spring boot: 2.1.3.RELEASE
- Java 8
- Springfox-swagger2: 2.9.2

SwaggerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey())).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class)).paths(PathSelectors.any()).
                        build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("API").description("DEMO").version("v1").build();
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("JWT", AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "header");
    }
}
```

This config show all Controllers, how to show only specific Controllers on Swagger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. Specific Controllers in same package**

```
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey())).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.tm.x.y.z.your.controller")).paths(PathSelectors.any()).
                        build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }
```

Show all Controllers in package com.tm.x.y.z.your.controller

**2. Specific Controllers in different packages**

- Create an class annotation(ex: ShowAPI annotation)

  ```
  import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
  import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  public @interface ShowAPI {
      String value() default "";
  }
  ```
- Add annotation to Controller

  ```
   @RestController
   @ShowAPI
   public class ExampleController {
   }
  ```
- Change swagger config

```
        @Bean
        public Docket api() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey())).select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(ShowAPI.class)).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
                    .apiInfo(apiInfo());
        }
```

Show all controller with class annotation is ShowAPI

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **@ApiIgnore** annotation.

1- To ignore controller class

```
@ApiIgnore 
@RestController
public class HelloController {
.....
.....
}
```

2- To ignore particular method

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    
    @ApiIgnore 
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/api/testmethod")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Swagger Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, Some Architect from your project must have applied same solution as suggested by @tienph (the top rated answer) and named the annotation as APIIgnore.